# JSON-Simple. Append to a JSONArray

Tags: java, json, json-simple

I am using the JSON-simple library to parse the Json format. How can I append something to a JSONArray? For e.g. consider the following json

```
{
    "a": "b"
    "features": [{/*some complex object*/}, {/*some complex object*/}]
}
```

I need to append a new entry in the `features`. 
I am trying to create a function like this:-

```
public void appendToList(JSONObject jsonObj, JSONObject toBeAppended){

    JSONArray arr = (JSONArray)jsonObj.get("features");

    //1) append the new feature
    //2) update the jsonObj
}
```

How to achieve steps 1 & 2 in the above code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

    String jsonString = "{\"a\": \"b\",\"features\": [{\"feature1\": \"value1\"}, {\"feature2\": \"value2\"}]}";
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) parser.parse(jsonString);

    JSONObject newJSON = new JSONObject();
    newJSON.put("feature3", "value3");

    appendToList(jsonObj, newJSON);

    System.out.println(jsonObj);
    }


private static void appendToList(JSONObject jsonObj, JSONObject toBeAppended) {

        JSONArray arr = (JSONArray) jsonObj.get("features");        
        arr.add(toBeAppended);
    }
```

This will fulfill your both requirements.

Comment: this does not satisfy the method signature i have provided above.

Comment: Instead of creating a new `JSONObject` instance, just add the 2nd argument in the method to the `arr` using the `put` call.

Comment: this is not what I meant. Just assume that I don't have any information what is inside the "complex object" I have mentioned above

Comment: The information of complex object is not needed as you have to add a new entry in JSONArray, As shown above you can add it using `add` method.

Comment: does adding it to the array update the original jsonObj?

Comment: Yes it will, I have printed original obj after method call. It is adding the same.

Answer (score -1):

Getting the array by: `jsonObj["features"]`, then you can add new item by assign it as the last element in the array ( `jsonObj["features"].length` is the next free place to add new element)

```
jsonObj["features"][jsonObj["features"].length] = toBeAppended;
```

[fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/x0kxnys2/)

Comment: OP is asking for an example in json-simple, not javascript.

Comment: While this source code may provide an answer, a few words of explanation would benefit current and future readers.

Comment: @TheThom I've added some explanation, thanks for your comment